# How upload video into server in Objective C ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have tried lot of methods. Nothing helps to upload. Some codes upload the video to server by working in simulator. But not upload the video in server by working on device. Please help me with working advice

My recent codes is:

```
NSURL *urlvalue = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoPath];
NSLog(@"The urlvalue is = %@",urlvalue);


NSData *urldata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlvalue];

 //NSURL *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
 //NSLog(@"fileurl is = %@",fileURL);

 //NSData *videoData1 = [videoPath dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 //NSData *videoData1=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];
NSData *videoData1=urldata;
 //NSLog(@"URL FOR VIDEO = %@",videoData);
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [videoData1 length]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.xyzxyzxyz.com/client/vine-clone/mobile/video_upload"]]];


 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setTimeoutInterval:60000];


 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
 [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

 //video
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 //[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Video Name with Date-Time
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ssa"];
NSString *currDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"video-%@.mov\"\r\n", currDate];
NSLog(@"String name::  %@",str);

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData1]];
 //[body appendData:videoData];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 //set the body to the request
 [request setHTTPBody:body];

 // send the request
 NSError *error13;
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error13];

 if(error13 != nil)
 {
 NSLog(@"erro is = %@",error13);
 }

 NSLog(@"return data %@",returnData);
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"response from server is= %@",returnString);
```

Comment: You need to describe what actually happens when you try the code. What specifically happens when you try to upload?

Comment: "Not working" is not a description of the problem. There are lots of ways that uploading a file could fail. You need to help people know what problem you're trying to solve instead of just telling people it's broken.

Comment: disappointments on stack overflow, waste of time

Comment: People are usually happy to help, but you have to want them to help you. If you refuse to provide crucial details illustrating the problem that you're having, you can't expect people to read your mind. You might want to check out Stack Overflow's "[How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @Tom Harrington ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a class I wrote a couple years ago in Objective-C for generating the request for a file upload.

First there's a data class that you create and load the parameters you're using for the request. The header file looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SDAPIRequestData : NSObject
// the url string you're calling to upload your file data to
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;
// the name of the file you're putting into the body
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filename;
// the data you're trying to upload
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *filedata;

@end
```

The class that generates the request looks like this: (first the header file)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SDAPIRequestData.h"

@interface SDAPIFileRequestSetup : NSObject
// init the class and pass the object containing the file data you just created
-(id) initWithRequestData:(SDAPIRequestData *)requestData;
// take the data generated and convert to a request to send via NSURLConnection or NSURLSession
-(NSURLRequest*) toRequest;
@end
```

Now for the implementation file that does the heavy lifting:

```
#import "SDAPIFileRequestSetup.h"
@interface SDAPIFileRequestSetup()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *contentType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *httpMethod;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *fileData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *boundary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fileType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filename;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *body;
@end

@implementation SDAPIFileRequestSetup
@synthesize boundary = _boundary,
        fileType = _fileType,
        filename = _filename,
        contentType = _contentType
;


-(id) initWithRequestData:(SDAPIRequestData *)requestData
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // setup instance properties with request parameters and default values
        self.urlString      = requestData.urlString;
        self.filename       = requestData.filename;
        self.httpMethod     = @"POST";
        self.boundary       = @"-----------------------------7771935987712374---------------------";
        self.contentType    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data boundary=%@",self.boundary];
        self.fileData       = requestData.filedata;

        // load any post parameters we want to include with the file data in the request
        [self setupPostParameters];
        // now add the file data to the request data
        [self setupFileParameters];
    }
    return self;
}

// this is called after instantiation to generate a request to be sent to the api
-(NSURLRequest*) toRequest
{
    // create the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

    // set any custom headers you need set

    // set the request method
    [request setHTTPMethod: self.httpMethod];

    // setup our content type header
    [request setValue: self.contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // set the header for our post data length
    [request setValue: self.contentLength forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

    // set the post data
    [request setHTTPBody: self.body];

    return request;
}


// step 1
-(void) setupPostParameters
{
    // generate post parameters
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                         // ADD ANY OTHER POST PARAMETERS YOUR API NEEDS HERE
                         @"type"        : self.fileType,
                         };

    // setup post variables
    [params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
    {
         [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", self.boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", obj] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     }];
}

-(void) setupFileParameters
{
    // setup file parameters
    if (self.fileData)
    {
        [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", self.boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", self.filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", self.fileType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [self.body appendData:self.fileData];
        [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    // set the http body
    [self.body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", self.boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}



-(NSURL*) url
{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
}

-(NSString*)contentLength
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[self.body length]];
}


-(void)setFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
    _filename = filename;

    // get the file extension
    NSString *fileExt = [[filename pathExtension] lowercaseString];

    // get our extension map
    NSDictionary *extMap = [self filetypeToExtensionMap];

    // retrieve the file type or default to png
    NSString *newType = extMap[fileExt] ? extMap[fileExt] : @"image/png";

    // set the filetype to go with the file extension
    [self setFileType:newType];
}

-(NSString*)filename
{
    return _filename;
}


-(NSDictionary*)filetypeToExtensionMap
{
return @{@"png"     : @"image/png",
         @"jpg"     : @"image/jpg",
         @"jpeg"    : @"image/jpeg",
         @"avi"     : @"video/avi",
         @"mpeg"    : @"video/mpeg",
         @"mpg"     : @"video/mpg",
         @"mov"     : @"video/mov",
         @"3gp"     : @"video/3gp",
         @"wmv"     : @"video/wmv",
         @"mp4"     : @"video/mp4",
         @"mpv"     : @"video/mpv"
         };
}


-(NSMutableData*) body
{
    if (! _body)
    {
        _body = [NSMutableData data];
    }

    return _body;
}

@end
```

To use create your SDApiRequestData instance and populate the properties. Then create an instance of SDApiFileRequestSetup and pass the data instance you just created. After instantiation call the 'toRequest' method to generate a request to pass to the server using NSURLSession or NSURLConnection.